# Which function gets invoked when a push notification received on Ionic 3 app?

Tags: angular, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 with cordova. I want to play a music on receiving a push notification from server. For achieving this I have to know which function gets called at the time of notification received. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the push plugin used. For the standard [cordova-plugin-push](https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push) the function is `.on('notification')`, however you must read the entire [documentation](https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md) before trying to implement this function. Its behaviour will depend on the app's status. Also, read the docs instead of jumping directly to ask questions here next time or your account will be blocked.